# URL Decode with Python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Is there a way to URL decode a string in Python 3

to take something like this

```
id%253D184ff84d27c3613d%26quality%3Dmedium
```

and decode it twice to get

```
id=184ff84d27c3613d&quality=medium
```

Answer (score 126):

Just use `urllib.parse.unquote()`:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.unquote('id%253D184ff84d27c3613d%26quality%3Dmedium')
'id%3D184ff84d27c3613d&quality=medium'
>>> urllib.parse.unquote('id%3D184ff84d27c3613d&quality=medium')
id=184ff84d27c3613d&quality=medium
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'`, instead I must use `urllib.unquote()` directly.

Comment: @Benjamin: You're using Python2. This is for Python3.

Comment: I don't know why it needs to be run twice, can you explain @Blender?

Comment: @Blender this should be `import urllib.parse`

Comment: I wonder why they did adopt "quote"/"unquote" instead of "encode"/"decode" :/

Comment: How would you convert this into a dictionary like {id:253D184ff84d27c3613d,quality:medium}  ?

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
s = 'id%253D184ff84d27c3613d%26quality%3Dmedium'
unquote(unquote(s))
```

It will return:

```
> 'id=184ff84d27c3613d&quality=medium'
```

Comment: Python3 organized `urllib` and `urllib2` into a single `urllib` with different sub-modules. This would work for Python2.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, what would be the correct way in Python3? `from urllib import parse.unquote`?

Comment: `from urllib.parse import unquote`. See my answer.

Comment: Nitpicking here, but you need to run the function twice. The URL has been encoded twice.