# python requests @ params

Tags: python, python-requests

I try to using request.get with '@' in params, but in output I have '%40' How I can decode this dict?

Using Python3

```
import requests

payload = {'OPERATION-NAME': 'findItemsByProduct','productId.@type':'ReferenceID'}

req = requests.post(url, params=payload)

print(req.url)
```

The output is - 'url?productId.%40type=ReferenceID'

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628152/url-decode-with-python-3) is what you're looking for?

Comment: I checked this too, does not work

Comment: Using [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote): `unquote("url?productId.%40type=ReferenceID")` returns
`'url?productId.@type=ReferenceID'`. What's wrong about that?

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Heya, the comment section isn't for discussing new problems that arise. If you've solved it partially and are getting new exceptions, it's time to open a new question (after doing proper research!) :)

Comment: You suggest a solution, maybe you firstly try it before publishing ?? Did you see it's a dict !!! And how you will use it in (param section of requests) I dont need a string formating I need to use the payload dict in requests params with '@' char!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160540/discussion-between-coal-and-therutubeify).

Answer (score 1):

Use "data" argument instead of params. You should also specify the header, in this case json and then convert the payload dict to json using json.dumps().

```
import requests
import json


payload = {'productId.@type':'ReferenceID'}

req = requests.post(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'}, data=json.dumps(payload))

print(req.url)
```

Comment: I see you answered OP, but didn't provide an explanation. Please include some context in your answer.

Comment: I forgot to include the header, try again and let me know. Make sure you have a valid url. BTW what you get is not the request (req) it's the response so you should rename req by resp.

Comment: TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'

Comment: What python are you using? Pyhton2 / Python3, What requests version??

Comment: My bad it's 'headers' plural. I didn't test the code just writing from my head. It should work.

Comment: Python 3.6.2, Requests 2.18.4

Comment: Sorry, but no effect !